# Change what appears when i click on a product

Tags: magento

i need to know how i can change the behavour of the "click event" on magento when i click on a product. Like, instead of showing its details, do somethign else. Going to page x or alert soemting, i dont care, just need some starting help on that. :) in details, i need to get lightbox instead of the details page. but imn new to magento and dont know where to start.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to execute something on the existing page, as opposed to redirecting the page to some alternative location. To do that, just add some JS to the page that intercepts the click event and performs whatever action you want. You could put this into your own JS file and load it on the product list page like this (local.xml):

```
<catalog_product_list>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>path/to/your/script.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_list>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe